# Enable/Disable Event Subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I am using Event Grid Subscriptions in Azure which gets triggered on Blob Created. However we have lot of files coming into this blob say 1000+.

What would like to do is disable the Event Subscriptions if I find any errors with any of the files.

Answer (score 5):

Enable/Disable Event Subscription in the AEG is not supported, however you can use a workaround using the suffix filter, for instance, **disabled**.

see, the following screen snippet:
[image]

Also, please vote the feedback to the AEG team for this feature, [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909934-azure-event-grid/suggestions/33974692-enable-disable-event-subscriptions#comments).

Comment: Thanks , How can I set the filter , please guide if possible with screenshot.